# How can I connect my LED strip lights?

Tags: lighting, led, cables

I bought this white-only LED strip lights off [amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GF5D0RE), and it has a DC jack. However, when I search on the internet, there seems to also be 4-wire cable and 2-wire cable.

I'm asking this because I want to attach a remote and a dimmer to the LED strip light, and the [remote dimmer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AHU2U7O) has 2-wire cable.

Can I connect the LED's DC jack to the dimmer? And how do I go from the dimmer to a 110V outlet?

Answer (score 2):

Usually you use the two outmost connection points for +/- 12VDC on the strip ... and usually + and - leads are marked by printed labels on the strips at each seperation mark.

For connection from power supply to the strip you either use the premounted socket (if any is mounted at the end of the strip) or you solder the cables coming from the transformer / DC source onto the connection pads.

With the shopping list of your OP I would do the following wiring

```
            +-------------+              +-------------+                +---------.
           ~|             |+ ---------- +|  in     out |+ ------------ +|
 110/220VAC |  Mains/12V  |    12VDC     |   Dimmer    |   12VDC PWM    |  Strip  ....
           ~|  converter  |- ---------- -|             |- ------------ -|
            +-------------+              +-------------+                +---------.
```

The power rating of your ACDC converter is a function of the length of LED strip you want to use. If I am not mistaken - a single tripple of LEDs (the smallest separable unit) takes 60mA ... so all 300 LEDs (100 sections) would require as much a 6000 mA (6A)

The current limit of the dimmer is 12A which is fine for the whole strip.

If you are using more than -say- half of the strip I would consider more than 1 feed point to avoid voltage drops along the strip.

Answer (score 1):

You still need a power supply, such as this: [http://www.amazon.com/Ledwholesalers-Power-Suppply-Driver-Transformer/dp/B0034GUEY4/ref=pd_sim_lg_1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0034GUEY4)

You go from the output of the PS, to the input of the dimmer module, from the output of the module to the strip. You can see right on the module where it says how it is connected.

Comment: So my question was how to connect the DC jack of the LED strip light to the 2-wire cable? Or may be the LED strip also has a 2-wire cable that the amazon picture does not show? And sorry for the really newbie question, but "connecting" simply means twisting the wires together (correct polarity of course) and put some tapes over, yes?

Comment: Actually no, this makes a really bad connection. Personally I would crimp it with "butt connectors". 

Actually I see now, the strip has a plug-in connector on it. A-ha! In this case I would still cut off that connector and crimp the splices. You really have no choice if you want to use that dimmer module.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I bought the strip, but not the dimmer. I've been trying to find a dimmer with DC jack but there's none to be found.

Comment: I doubt you'll find one. Those connectors on the strip LEDs are pretty useless IMO, unless of course you find something from the same manufacturer that will work together. I've installed a few of these and haven't seen it work yet.